# Get the position of item from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have found the code that runs trough my list of leader board and returns the corresponding value. But I would need to return the position of the item in the list. How should I modify the code so it would return the position (index) of the item.

Thanks.

```
//query for sorting by score
    score = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Leaders");
    final Query query = score.orderByChild("uID").equalTo(mCurrentUser.getUid());

    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Iterator<DataSnapshot> iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            int length = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

            String[] sampleString = new String[length];

            while(i < length) {
                sampleString[i] = iterator.next().getValue().toString();
                //Log.d(Integer.toString(i), sampleString[i]);

                //print the value of current score
                Toast.makeText(LeaderBoardActivity.this,sampleString[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                i++;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use `FirebaseListAdapter` as mentioned in a previous answer. Will work for sure. The `populateView()` method has the exact fied that you need, the `position`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited the code based on your comments. Since you only care about the position and score...

```
// you will need to query the database based on scores
score = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Leaders");
final Query query = score.orderByChild("Score");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // get total leaders. Let's say total leader is 5 persons
        int total = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        // let's say userB is actually 2nd in the list
        int i = 0;
        // loop through dataSnapshot
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String uID = childSnapshot.child("uID").getValue();
            if (uID.equals(mCurrentUser.getUid()) {
                // the list is ascending, when finally reach userB, i = 3
                int userPlace = total - i;    // gives 2
                int score = childSnapshot.child("Score").getValue(Interger.class);
                break;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Note that this can be very bandwidth consuming. As you get more and more users, you will need to download all the user data for each query. It might be better if you just show the top 5 leaders etc.

Comment: what im trying to do is basically provide the position on the leader board. For example user A has 80, points user B has 60. So the position would be laid like this User A 1st User B 2nd and so on.

Comment: How do you intend to retrieve the values from the list? Please give an example of the list. Do you need to include user name in the list?

Is it `(1) User A - 80 (2) User B - 60 (3) User C....` or you don't really care about the sequence and just want `(User A) - 80, (User B) - 60, (User C)...` The item in the bracket is the "key" to call back the values in the list later.

Comment: I do care about sequence, that is the main idea of leader board to show in which position user are in. I don't really need to show his name ...just need to show that value of score and the index value of it

Comment: But the way your query seems to only return the score of 1 user? You are using `.equalTo(mCurrentUser.getUid())`, so that will only return the score of that particular user.

Comment: Yes that is correct...As I want to know in which position the current user is in.

Comment: My point is, when you did such query, you are only getting the score of ONE user, not a LIST of users. Have you tested what is returned from your query?

Comment: Yes I did..As you were saying it returned only only one user. But I thought it was returning it from the whole list. So I assume that my query is wrong. So then how could I get the whole list of scores and then show the index value (for score) of the current user?

Comment: Thanks will try it out

Answer (score 0):

I use following method to change child value by position, hope this can give you some helps:

```
DataSnapshot targetData;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    targetReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshots) {
            targetData = dataSnapshots;        //save in global variable
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

private void yourMethod() {
    int index = 0;

    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : targetData.getChildren()) {
        if (index == 1) {        //your target index
            DatabaseReference currentReference = childSnapshot.getRef();

            currentReference.setValue("xxx");
        }

        index++;
    }
}
```