# How to get a value of Firebase by index?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase depending on the position. If I don't know, what the key of the first value is like, how am I able to access the value of the first position?

```
    ticketCodes.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>>() {};
            List<String> yourStringArray = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);


// Here I want to receive the value of the first index in firebase without knowing what the key is. 
//I am not able to. Though if I put "get(firstKey)" it gives me the value of the first index.

String value = yourStringArray.get(0);
```

Is there another way of how to get access of the first position in this List?
My database looks like the following:

[image: though i don't know, that the first key is 1 and the second 2 and so on]

Comment: Same? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43328431/4409113

Comment: I edited the above. My database is slightly different than the one you linked